# Accessing IIS Express hosted website remotely on Azure VM

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ip, virtual-machine

I have Visual Studio solution running in Debug mode using IIS Express on an Azure Virtual Machine.

I can RDP into this machine using its domain:

myapp.cloudapp.net:port#

IIS Express is running:

localhost:2799

I have also created an End Point using HTTP, mapping public port 80 to 2799.

But the URL http://myapp.cloudapp.net does not connect or relay through to the webpage running at localhost:2799. Is there something else that needs to be done to make this happen?

Comment: Few thoughts - What error do you get when you browse? Is the http binding correct? Also, don't know if an Azure VM has http port open (through firewall) by default.. might be worth a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the only thing you need to modify - is to add new rule in your firewall to open port 2799. 
Try to disable firewall and check whether the website available.
If the page is shown - add appropriate rules to firewall.

Comment: I turned off the firewall and still cannot access 80 or 2799.

Comment: This is how my app is configured [See screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/io3PFAK.png) . The only things I've changed were add port mapping and add firewall rules. You might try to configure full-weight IIS and then configure IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

There are three changes you might need to make.

1.Tell IIS Express itself to bind to all ip addresses and hostnames. In your .config file (typically
    %userprofile%\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config, or $(solutionDir).vs\config\applicationhost.config for Visual Studio 2015), find your site's binding element, and add :

```
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2799:*" />
```

2. Setup the bit of Windows called 'http.sys'. As an administrator, run the command:

```
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:2799/ user=everyone
```

3. Allow IIS Express through Windows firewall. 
   Start / Windows Firewall with Advanced Security / Inbound Rules / New Rule...
      Program %ProgramFiles%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
   OR Port 2799 TCP

Now when you start iisexpress.exe you should see a message such as

```
Successfully registered URL "http://*:2799/" for site "myapp" application "/"
```

This configuration combined with your endpoint mapping should do the trick
Hope this helps
Best regards
Stéphane